# tapGestureRecognizer not firing action when on a UIScrollView Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uitextfield

I have a ViewController that has a UIScrollView and the keyboard wont dismiss when using a tapGestureRecognizer. The action wont even fire. Normally this works fine on other ViewControllers that I have built.

I think the UIScrollView is eating up all the touch events. I know you can set the UIScrollView to dismiss the keyboard but I need it to recognize a tapGesture. Here is my code:

```
@IBOutlet var tapGesture: UITapGestureRecognizer!

tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "tapRecognized:")
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    tapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = false

func tapRecognized(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer){

    self.truckName.resignFirstResponder()
    self.engineMake.resignFirstResponder()

    truckName.endEditing(true)

    self.view.endEditing(true)

    println("tap gesture")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, the whole reason it wasn't working was because I was adding the tapGesture to the superview and not the content view inside the scrollview. Im glad I solved it but hate when you spend hours trying to and as soon as you post the question it hits you.